# Apache2 a2ensite: ERROR: Site /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7aBP.png)
I realize this has been asked before, but this is not the same error and I am not able use the same solution(s) of moving the file from sites-enabled or renaming the file with a .conf extension.

The config file exists in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and has the .conf extension.

No matter what I name it, it says "does not exist." Is there a permissions issue? Does www-data need access to the conf file (they are owned by root)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/a2ensite.8.html

Try running

```
a2ensite example.com
```

Comment: I tried to delete the question after I found the solution and YES, not using the entire path fixes the issue. D'oh.